# Pyqtgraph Setting Label Styles

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, pyqtgraph

I have a question regarding the formatting of various text objects within a graph. While trying to make my plots look good (for example for publishing purposes) I have encountered the issue that text elements seem to have quite different requirements when it comes to formatting.

For example formatting the title of a graph is done by

```
pw.setTitle('test', **{'color': '#FFF', 'size': '14pt'})
```

while formatting a label is done with

```
pw.setLabel('test', **{'color': '#FFF', 'font-size': '14pt'})
```

Then when it comes to formatting the text of ticks I have to create a QFont and manipulates it's properties, for example

```
tickFont = QtGui.QFont()
tickFont.setPointSize(14)
pw.getAxis('left').tickFont = tickFont
```

Therefore I wonder if it's just me who has an improper understanding of the classes or if it really is that different for each label. I understand of course that there are subtle differences in which kinds of objects are involved and how they are controlled. However it makes me wonder if some kind of unified interface would be desireable, especially to produce publishable graphs.

Greets,
Fabian.

Comment: This might not be really useful but I would not use pyqtgraph for published-ready plots. I love pyqtgraph but I think this is not its designed purpose and therefore going against it could be painful. I would use matplotlib or seaborn instead

Comment: True, I primarily apreciate the performance and ease to integrate into Qt GUIs. I still wonder if what I am doing is the "accepted" way, or if I am overseeing something.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I have found that if you apply a style to the label, if the background is black, it will not show.

Don't do:

```
styles = {'color':'w', 'font-size':'5px'}
self.plt1.setBackground('k')
self.plt1.setLabel('left', 'Speed (kn)', **styles)
self.plt1.setLabel('bottom', 'Time', **styles)
```

Do:

```
self.plt1.setBackground('k')
self.plt1.setLabel('left', 'Speed (kn)')
self.plt1.setLabel('bottom', 'Time')
```